# Adventures in Vim Level 4 replacing char r{1}, is not working for me

Tags: vim-adventures

In Level 4 for replacing char r{1} in this instance.

1. manoeuvre the cursor over the integer 0
2. type and r{1}
3. the command fades and nothing changed??

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are like me, then you're using `r` with the wrong character.

I thought the characters in black were the "wrong" characters and the characters in red were the "right" characters, as if the text had been proofread. But players are actually supposed to replace the red text with the original black text.

For example, if the key has black text that says `[p][o][o][r]` with a red "p" over the `[r]`, you should put your cursor over the `[r]` and type `rr`.